# Addition of elements from a list

Tags: prolog

I want to make a program, which generates elements from 1 to N, save them in a list and make the addition oft them. N is depending on the length of the list. For example, when I ask for "add(L,A)" it should give me

```
"L=[], A=0",
"L=[1], A=1",
"L=[1,1], A=2",
"L=[1,2], A=3",
"L=[2,1], A=3",
"L=[2,2], A=4",
"L=[1,1,1], A=3" and so on.
```

It should work with the var and between predicate. My code so far is:

```
add(L,A) :-
    var(L),
    length(L,N),
    between(1,N,E),
    add(E,AZ),
    A is E + AZ.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `library(clpfd)`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

add(L, A) :-
    length(L, Length),
    L ins 1..Length,
    sum(L, #=, A),
    label(L).
```

Note that this answer has some problems. For example:

```
?- add(L,3).
L = [1, 2] ;
L = [2, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 1] ;
<infinite loop>
```

This is due to `length/2` which will try lengths that are too big. Adding a constraint that `Length` must be less or equal to `A` does not solve this issue.

Fixing this would make the predicate much less readable. A temporary fix could be to impose that either `A` is a variable or that `L` is not, and throw an exception otherwise.